# how to set progress bar

Tags: android

```
package com.example.tabactivity;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class circularlistparsing extends ActivityGroup {

    public int currentPage = 1;
    public ListView lisView1;
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
    static final String KEY_ITEM2 = "info";
    static final String KEY_NAME1 = "";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public Button btnNext;
    public Button btnPre;
    public static String url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetCircularList";
    TextView txtreord;
    TextView totalpage;
    TextView pagenumber;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txtreord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recored);
        totalpage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalpage);
        pagenumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);

        // listView1
        lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    //  new YourTask().execute();
        // Next
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        // Perform action on click
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;

    //          new YourTask().execute();
                ShowData();
                pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage+"]");
            }
        });

        // Previous
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        // Perform action on click
        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage - 1;

        //      new YourTask().execute();
                ShowData();
                pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage+"]");
            }
        });

    //  new YourTask().execute();
        ShowData();
    }

    public void ShowData() {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM2);

        int displayPerPage = 10; // Per Page
        int TotalRows = nl.getLength();

        txtreord.setText( TotalRows+"Records|"); // number of records

        int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
        int TotalPage = 0;
        if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
            TotalPage = 1;
        } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
        } else {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
            TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
        }

        totalpage.setText("Page[" + TotalPage);

        int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
        if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
            indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
        }

        // Disabled Button Next
        if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previos
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Load Data from Index
        int RowID = 1;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        // RowID
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(i);

            String date = e2.getAttribute(KEY_DATE);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));

            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);

            // String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME).replace("|", "|\n")
            // .replace("|", "");
            //

            String mytime = date;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
            Date myDate = null;
            try {
                myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

            } catch (ParseException t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

            // System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrr"+finalDate);

            String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);

            int a = Heading.indexOf("|");
            String beforeSubString = Heading.substring(0, a);
            String afterSubString = Heading.substring(a, Heading.length())
                    .replace("|", "") + "[" + finalDate + "]";
            // String
            // final1="<b>"+beforeSubString+"<b>"+"|"+afterSubString.replace("|",
            // "|\n")
            // .replace("|", "");
            // String k=Html.fromHtml(final1).toString();
            //
            // Html.fromHtml(final1);

            map.put(KEY_NAME, beforeSubString);
            map.put(KEY_NAME1, afterSubString);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

            RowID = RowID + 1;

        }

        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(circularlistparsing.this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME1, KEY_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName, R.id.textView1 });
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

        lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(circularlistparsing.this, detail.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                // i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });




        }





    class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                   dialog = ProgressDialog.show(circularlistparsing.this, "", "Please wait..");
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            try {
               // doSomethingHeavy();
                   // publishProgress(...);

                ShowData();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //...
            } 

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }




}
```

Hii please this code show data function is for displaying data when i m using  new YourTask().execute(); in place of show data then its showing Progress bar but not displaying data but able to read data while when we user showdata() function den it display data please tell me how to implement progress bar .

Answer (score 0):

implement this code

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

         ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "",
                "Loading...");

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
       try {
       // doSomethingHeavy();
           // publishProgress(...);

        ShowData();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //...
    } 

    return null;
}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        dialog .getProgress();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        dialog .dismiss();


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: progress it showing Error here  and protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            //do hard work here Showdata();
                                return params;
        }

Comment: there we ll set function Showdata();

Comment: But how will use this still not displaying data when i use new YourTask().execute(); this code On NExt previous and in  one more place

Comment: But how i will use new YourTask().execute(); this in previoues next Button and in one more place if we replace ShowData() funtion with new YourTask().execute(); then it doesn't display data –

Comment: is there any error or not in the AsyncTask class.print some value in your ShowData() method to know it print value or not

Comment: NO Error Just blank coming in Listview

Comment: your method not fetch data just print the value and check in logcat methd ShowData() parse value or not

Comment: You should not call ShowData()  after YourTask().execute() in button click methods

Answer (score 0):

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Currentactivity.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.show();
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //do hard work here
                            return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progress.getProgress();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        progressBar.dismiss();


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how i will use new YourTask().execute(); this in previoues next Button and in one more place if we replace ShowData() funtion with new YourTask().execute(); then it doesn't display data

Comment: why dont you call ShowData() in AsyncTask

Comment: new YourTask().execute();
  ShowData(); in this manner  i call den data is coming and showing progressbar for bit time is it right?

Comment: you have to add ShowData() in doInBackground() method

Comment: yes i did already But what code i will use in button previous and button next or in one more place please see it in my code